# Ember.JS transitionToRoute from ApplicationController action stack exceeded

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the following in my template:

```
= hb 'render "partials/search_field" controller="application"'
```

which executes an action on `insertNewLine`, "search".

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend(
  needs: ["search"]

  query: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.search.query")

  actions:
    search: ->
      query = @get('query')
      @transitionToRoute('search', {queryParams: {query:query}})
)
```

In my search route, the query param refreshes the model:

```
App.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  App.PageableRouteMixin,

  queryParams:
    query:
      refreshModel: false

  model: (params) ->
    @store.findQuery('search',params)

)
```

If I use the rendered partial, from any state other than the index state, it works fine. However, if I try from the initial state, the index, I get the following error in my console:

[image]

Debug output follows:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.7.1+pre.f095a455 
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.12-canary 
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.1 
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
Attempting URL transition to / 
Transition #0: application: calling beforeModel hook 
Transition #0: application: calling deserialize hook 
Transition #0: application: calling afterModel hook 
Transition #0: index: calling beforeModel hook 
Transition #0: index: calling deserialize hook 
Transition #0: index: calling afterModel hook 
Transition #0: Resolved all models on destination route; finalizing transition. 
Rendering application with default view <(subclass of Ember.View):ember416> Object {fullName: "view:application"} 
Rendering index with default view <(subclass of Ember.View):ember437> Object {fullName: "view:index"} 
Transitioned into 'index' 
Transition #0: TRANSITION COMPLETE. 
Ember Inspector Active VM1234:161
  Ember.Binding<ember596>(_parentView.context.query -> value) <- i Class {placeholder: "Search jobs", onInsertNewline: "search", classNames: Array[3], valueBinding: Binding, templateData: Object…} 
  Ember.Binding<ember596>(_parentView.context.query -> value) <- io Class {placeholder: "Search jobs", onInsertNewline: "search", classNames: Array[3], valueBinding: Binding, templateData: Object…} 
  Ember.Binding<ember596>(_parentView.context.query -> value) <- ios Class {placeholder: "Search jobs", onInsertNewline: "search", classNames: Array[3], valueBinding: Binding, templateData: Object…} 
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded 
  Ember.assert 
  get 
  ControllerMixin.reopen.transitionToRoute
  ControllerMixin.reopen.transitionToRoute
  ControllerMixin.reopen.transitionToRoute
  ...
```

Comment: I think this is because I was trying to do this from the ApplicationController level rather than something lower, but can't confirm as to why yet.

Comment: What's App.PageableRouteMixin?  And if you remove the `query` alias does it still happen?

Comment: Thanks @Kingpin2k, removing it doesn't change anything. It deals with page query param specifically. Nevertheless, removal didn't fix it. I think it was simply transitionToRoute being called from ApplicationController, rather than on a child controller.